# Why My Application Badge Icon in home Screen Not showing?

Tags: android, push-notification, samsung-mobile

I am developing an application.

My problem is , in **samsung s5 with marshmellow** and **samsung s7 with naugut** ,

When I receive push notification from **FCM**, I can see it in Notification Panel, but in phone's home screen, on App icon - badge - i can not see it. Why?

Even Samsung devices are showing badge icon for Whatsapp and Facebook. But not showing for my application when my application is on **killed mode**.

This is happening in particular this two devices, but on mi phone it's showing,

I have tried to integrate this library and search many times but , no available :(
https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: even I am facing the same issue with my Galaxy S7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution and its working for me.

Previously, I was using **11.8.0('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0')** for FCM. But I downgrade it to **11.2.0('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0')**.
With the help of downgrading, I am able to get access to below method,

```
@Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
// This method will be called even if application is in killed mode.
}
```

With the help of [3rd party Badge count library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger), I am able to show badge count for my application and it's perfectly working for Samsung device.

Comment: @avik: It works for me only if I used the firebase messaging version "11.2.0". Also, you need to integrate 3rd party badge count library to show badge count.(not working on Stock OS)